# Bolding parent categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

I'm using a theme in wordpress where there's a search form to display posts based on the categories selected.

I have the categories falling into place by the following code:

```
    <option value="1">Parent category</option>
    <option value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;subcategory</option>
    <option value="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;subcategory</option>
    <option value="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;subcategory</option>
```

My goal is to bold the parent category. I've checked all my theme files if i an edit this, tried adding a CSS class which i could target, but clearly its a query, which i cannot seem to configure.

Can anybody let me know how i could bold the parent category? Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the option value of the parent category you can just write CSS like this:

```
option[value="1"] {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Slightly more detail and proof of concept here:

https://jsfiddle.net/h6y23ge1/1/

Comment: I tried it on the site but for somehow, even if the inspect element shows that the CSS is being pulled, it doesn't get applied. You can check the labels in the search form on the site here: http://beautifuldev.co.uk/

Comment: Are you referring to the "Category" and "Location" fields?

Comment: I looked at that page and the <select> and <optiions> are hidden from view.  Thus, you will not be able to change the way the page looks by styling them.  Are you trying to bold "East England" and "Greater London"?

Comment: Yep, I'm looking to bold the option elements in the select form. That is the options under Categories and Location. For example, "Accomodation" ,"Double beds" and so on, based on the value.. Is that possible? Thanks for your time!  @vlasits

Comment: That won't be possible using CSS because the only difference in the HTML between "Accommodation" and "  Double Bed" is the text itself and the presence of a few spaces before "  Double Bed".  Two options for doing this are 1> to get whatever tool is creating the html to apply a class to the ones that are not indented that you could target in css (e.g. .parent-category { font-weight: bold;}) or 2> to write some javascript or jquery that identifies the items that don't start with two non-breaking spaces and assign them that same class.

Comment: Thanks very much @vlasits Any idea why even applying the style through inspect element also won't be applied? I mean if you literally edit the HTML through the code inspector and inline the CSS style, its not working. That's what's puzzling me... Anyways, Thanks for looking into it for me!

Comment: Probably because you have the wrong element.  As I said above, the <option> element is not visible on the page.  The element you see on the page is a div like this `<div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-19" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;En suite</div>`  When I add styles to that div in the code inspector it shows up on the screen just as you'd expect.

Comment: That's it! I got it. That's what was the missing bit, I found there's an id for the div above the span and i can target than and style and bold whatever i want! you're the champ man. Thanks for your time!

Comment: for those who're looking for the solution, I used nth element and styled the elements in the <ul> since the text's id was dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent option is always the first within the select it would be better to use the following.

```
select option:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;    
}
```